# Why do files end up in JBoss tmp but not the deployment

Tags: eclipse, deployment, jboss

I have a JBoss server whereby when I deploy my ear file from Eclipse, I'm ending up with a whole bunch of jar files missing from the lib/ directory. Upon further investigation, I have found these files - they're in the JBoss server's tmp/vfs-nested.tmp directory. The timestamps all confirm that they're "fresh" from the latest Eclipse server instance publish action I kick off, but I'm perplexed as to why they're residing in this tmp directory and not in the application's (failed) deployment to the server.

JBoss documentation indicates "The tmp directory is used by JBoss to store temporarily files such as unpacked deployments." but I'm unsure as to what the order is or why things are there but not in the deployed application.

Any help?

Dave

Comment: I was really hoping this would disappear after moving to the Red Hat branded Eclipse CodeReady. But yet this issue remains. The link between Eclipse and JBoss seems to be flaky and if you don't manually clean out files you risk picking up old stale bits. Apparently the JBoss tools plugin isn't tested thoroughly. Wish I had a better solution than manually deploying war files